# Is there a way to use any .net dll in React Native?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, react-native, dll

I have .dll files for the connect printer, api and sql operations. I want to use my .dll files in my React Native app but I didn't find how can I import these files. So, is there any way for the import custom .dll files in the React Native?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure this will be possible or not, coz you are trying to c# dll(server side) in react code(client side), alternative approach would be to expose the dll functionallity via api and use it in javascript.